# Java Multi Dimensional array/2d array

Tags: java, 2d

a method called booking that accepts an integer row number and the number of seats

requested, then fills the first available block of adjacent seats in the row (if possible).  If

successful, return true (if not, return false). I have attempted this question, i was wondering if i am doing it right and if not what mistake am i making in this question. Below is the output of the question. This is part of the question i  am attempting.The x are booked and - are not booked

*----------

*----------

*----------

*xxxxx-----

*----------

```
public boolean booking(int row , int seat)
    {
        if(seat[row]== 0 || seat [row]== 1 || seat [row] == 2 || seat[row] == 4 )
        {

            for (int i = 0 ; i < seat; i++)
            {
                System.out.print(seat[row][i] == "x");

            }
            return true;
        }   
        if(seat[row]==3)
        {
            if(seat  > 5)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else 
            {
                for(int  i = 0; i < seat; i++)
                {
                    seat[35+i] == "x"; 
                    return true;
                }

            }



        }
    }
```

Comment: ----------
----------
----------
xxxxx-----
----------

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I went through and analyze your code.

Not trying to be rude but, highly recommend learning syntax before arrays her are some major things to look over

```
seat [row]== 1// if you have a 2D arrays you will have to add on another []
```

It should be 
    seat[row][col] == 1

Another problem is

```
System.out.print(seat[row][i] == "x"); // good you have the col but you can't tell the System.out.print to print a boolean, It wants a String.

//also
seat[35+i] == "x";

== is a boolean statement it does not assign anything.
```